# Removing content in cell using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a smart way to clean this content up "date2022-01-09T15:33:24.785Z" automatically. The output I'm looking for is the date, "2022-01-09".

Any ideas?

If the heading wasn't clear enough. I have a google sheet that updates automatically, but I'm having trouble with the format of the input in one och the columns, where I only want the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"date2022-01-09T15:33:24.785Z".split(/[a-zA-z]/g).filter(e => e)[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'date2022-01-09T15:33:24.785Z'.match(/date([^A-Z]*)/)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, that piece of code got the job done, as well as the answer above.